# /subscribers/{imsi} のリターンコードについて

Tags: soracom

API リファレンスには、指定されたSubscriberが存在しないときにHTTP Status Code が 404 と記載されているのですが、HTTP Status Code で 400 が返ってきます。
エラーコードは、400が正しいのでしょうか？それとも404が正しいのでしょうか？

Response Body:

```
{
   "code": "SEM0001",
   "message": "No such resource found"
}
```

以下のAPIも同様でした

- /subscribers/{imsi}/update_speed_class
- /subscribers/{imsi}/activate
- /subscribers/{imsi}/deactivate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ご指摘ありがとうございます。

ご報告いただいた API 全てにつきまして、Subscriber が存在しない場合には API Reference にありますとおりステータスコード 404 を返却するのが正しい動作です。

修正させていただきます。